# Cannot set navigation bar item image in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I am trying to customize a bar button item. I dragged it in the navigation bar and I can display text and predefined identifiers.

However it does not display custom images (44x44 & 22x22 px).

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: hey you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think may be you did not give the Path Extention. It will be "10-medical.png" or other path extention instead png like jpg gif etc.

Comment: Since the images are in Images.xcassets, xcode will recognize the extension. BTW the filename was autocompleted.